Gitlab configure workflows on target branches on group level
In Gitlab, is it possible to setup workflow target branches as described here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/index.html#configure-workflows-for-target-branches
but on a group level, rather than project level? We have multiple projects within a group that should prescribe to the same rule.
Alternatively does the Gitlab RestApi expose an endpoint to implement this on project level? This will allow me to create a script to update the workflow on each project in bulk.

I found nothing in REST API, GraphQL nor via terraform documentation.
